# Couldn't find Player with 'id' - but there the one is in DB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

```
class MatchesController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @match = Match.create(match_params)
    @player = Player.find(params[:winner_player_id])
    @player.update_rank.save
    redirect_to @match
  end

  private

    def match_params
      params.require(:match).permit(:loserscore, :winner_player_id, :loser_player_id, :date)
    end
end
```

> Request
>
> Parameters:
>
> {"utf8"=>"✓", 
>   "authenticity_token"=>"z979mCv50nfgzHYjO/OgKNuxTC7UT7GedgDjHYiK6RY=", 
>   "match"=>{"winner_player_id"=>"14",  "loser_player_id"=>"11", 
>   "loserscore"=>"1",  "date"=>""},  "commit"=>"Create Match"}

But I'm sure there is the Player with id=14 in DB. I check in console, and when I go to:

> http://localhost:3000/players/14

I can see this player's page.

Any idea what is the problem?

The browser gives:

> Couldn't find Player without an ID
>
> def create if @match = Match.create(match_params) @winner =
>   Player.find(params[:winner_player_id])

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According your log, `params` has a nested hash `"match"=>{"winner_player_id"=>"14"....` fix:

```
@player = Player.find(params[:winner_player_id])
# params[:winner_player_id] return `nil`
# and an expression `Player.find(nil)`
# raises error Couldn't find Player without an ID
```

to:

```
@player = Player.find(params[:match][:winner_player_id])
```